# Vertically Align A Div

Tags: html, css

Does anyone have reliable markup/ CSS that vertically align a div across all browsers?
Can get the following working in Firefox but not others..

```css
.parent { display: table; }
.child { display: table-cell; }  /* this panel is to align vertically in the middle*/
```

Comment: are you saying the key changes to my markup are height:50%; to the child and adding position: relative; margin: 0 auto; to the parent? thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you are vertical aligning simple text you can do:

```css
.container { height:300px; line-height:300px }
```

If you want to vertical aligng a div then you will need to use some javascript in order to make it work in all browsers.